# android scale up or down views

Tags: android, view, scale

I have a problem. I have my images in every drawable density. Now im facing the problem in density hdpi, that have a lot of resolutions.

In a layout i have like 50 views. I need to scale up or down those views programatically because using dp and all of that its not enough to suppor every resoultion.

How can i scale up or down every view not writting 4 lines per view getting the Layout parameters, changing the size, etc. Like iterating the list of views or something like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your views are inside a `ViewGroup`, you can use `getChildAt(index)` and `getChildCount()` to iterate through your views.

`LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `FrameLayout` are `ViewGroup`'s, so you can use this approach.